# JSTL <c:param>; assign a value

Tags: javascript, jstl

I just create this javascript function and i want to assign the passed parameter (a) at a param but I don't know how can I do it. This way doesn't work.

```
<script>
function pass(a){
<c:url value="/mypage.jsp" var="completeURL">
  <c:param name="id" value=a/>
</c:url>
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**I don't think its possible.**

Could you please elaborate what you want to achieve so can suggest some workaround

Comment: I develop a site in JSP and now I want to pass a value from the client side to the server side so JSP can use it. The same think that happen when I submit a form but I don't want to use a submit button